# How to prevent tested functions from outputting to terminal when using QuickCheck monadicIO

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm wondering if there's some way to prevent functions from printing to the terminal when they're being tested through GHCI with QuickCheck and monadicIO.

For example, say I have the following code:

```hs
import Test.Hspec
import Test.Hspec.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic (assert, monadicIO, pick, run)

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Something to test" $ do
    it "What I'm testing" $ do
      prop_exampleTest

prop_exampleTest :: Property
prop_exampleTest = monadicIO $ do
  num    <- pick arbitrary
  newNum <- run $ exampleFunc num
  assert $ num == newNum
```

I just want to test the return value of `exampleFunc`. However, if it uses `putStrLn`, then it will print to the terminal with each check.

```hs
exampleFunc :: Int -> IO Int
exampleFunc n = do
  putStrLn "One trick is to tell 'em stories that don't go anywhere - like the time I caught the ferry over to Shelbyville. I needed a new heel for my shoe, so, I decided to go to Morganville, which is what they called Shelbyville in those days. So I tied an onion to my belt, which was the style at the time. Now, to take the ferry cost a nickel, and in those days, nickels had pictures of bumblebees on 'em. Give me five bees for a quarter, you'd say..."
  return n
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Something like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently might work, though I can’t be absolutely sure.

Comment: @bradrn Yeah, you're right. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bradrn commented, this can be done using the [silently](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently) package. Just apply your function as an argument to its `silence` function:

```hs
import Test.Hspec
import Test.Hspec.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic (assert, monadicIO, pick, run)
-- Add the import statement for the silently 'silence' function.
import System.IO.Silently (silence)

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Something to test" $ do
    it "What I'm testing" $ do
      prop_exampleTest

prop_exampleTest :: Property
prop_exampleTest = monadicIO $ do
  num    <- pick arbitrary
  -- instead of running my function directly, apply it as an argument to silence
  newNum <- run $ silence (exampleFunc num)
  assert $ num == newNum


exampleFunc :: Int -> IO Int
exampleFunc n = do
  putStrLn "One trick is to tell 'em stories that don't go anywhere - like the time I caught the ferry over to Shelbyville. I needed a new heel for my shoe, so, I decided to go to Morganville, which is what they called Shelbyville in those days. So I tied an onion to my belt, which was the style at the time. Now, to take the ferry cost a nickel, and in those days, nickels had pictures of bumblebees on 'em. Give me five bees for a quarter, you'd say..."
  return n
```